# Servlet chaining - simple example

Tags: java, servlets, requestdispatcher

I see a strange issue in a simple servlet chaining example that I am trying:

Servlet 1:

```
public class gatewayservlet extends HttpServlet {

  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request , 
    HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException , IOException {
        doGet(request,response);
  }

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request , 
    HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException , IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/plain");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    name = request.getParameter("name");

    RequestDispatcher rd = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/justServlets/secondservlet");

    if(name!=null) {
      request.setAttribute("UserName",name);
      rd.forward(request , response);
      // Forward the value to another Secondservlet
    } else {
      response.sendError(response.SC_BAD_REQUEST, 
        "UserName Required");
    }

  }

}
```

Servlet 2:

```
public class secondservlet extends HttpServlet {

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request , 
    HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException , IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/plain");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String UserName = (String)request.getAttribute("UserName");

    out.println("The UserName is "+ UserName);

  }


  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request , 
    HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException , IOException {
        doGet(request,response);
  }

}
```

And the invoking form:

```
<html>
<body>
<FORM ACTION="/justServlets/gateway" METHOD=POST>
<P>Please Fill the Registration Form</p><br>
Enter Your Name<input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit" value="send">
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

The 'POST' gives a 405(Method not allowed) error.
However ,invoking the first servlet as ..../justServlets/gateway?name=Socrates works.
Whats the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens when the servlet you are forwarding do lacks a handler for the same method (in this case POST) as was originally handled. Make sure servlet2 does indeed handle doPost and that you are indeed forwarding to servlet2.

Comment: It does - its a simple redirect to the GET.And it is being forwarded to the correct servlet - and as the GET does bring me response from the second servlet for the same code.

Comment: It seemed to be a app server caching issue somehow.
A re-start of the server and the application works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `/justServlets` is the context path of your webapp, the code which forwards should use `/secondservlet` and not `/justServlets/secondservlet`, because, as [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> The pathname must begin with a / and is interpreted as **relative to the current context root**.

(emphasis mine)

As it is, you're forwarding to `/justServlets/justServlets/secondservlet`, which probably doesn't exist.

Comment: The redirect is workin fine as I am gettin gthe response from the second servlet with a GET request on the first servlet.It is just the POST which is failing